# jQuery Mobile dynamically add data-role in external page

Tags: jquery, mobile, dynamic, external

I have a simple index page.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('a').attr("data-role", "button"); 
        $('a').attr("data-transition", "slide");    
    })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page">
        <a href="2.php">Go to next page</a>
    </div>

</body>
```

..and it's my next page

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('a').attr("data-role", "button");
        $('a').attr("data-transition", "slide");
    })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <a href="index.php">asd</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

When i'm click to 'next page' link, JQM can't read 'data-role="button"'. Therefor, link on the next page, looks like simple link.

So, how can i allow it to read dynamically?

Comment: why don't you use the data attributes inside the button?

Comment: I'm using a CMS. i can't add data-role attribute. I have to insert dynamically

Answer (score 0):

In order to tell framework that the styles of a button should be applied in a certain element, you have to call the button plugin on any selector.

Note that this code should be placed inside a page event(pageshow, pagecreate, pageinit, etc). in order to work you need to put an id in each of the divs with data-role="page" which are your pages

In your case should be

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page_id',  function(){
   $('a').button();

   //would be better to put an id in your button
   $('#button_id').button();
});
```

Take a look at the api docs to know what methods you can use once you call the button plugin.
http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/

Comment: It's working for a single page. But when i click to button, i'm having a same problem on the next page.

Comment: use the page events to call the button plugin when you need . Take a look at my answer, just updated . if you don't know about page events, take a look at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: I have tried with page events. But i couldn't. Maybe you can tell what i have  to write in my scripts.